# How can I horizontally align text in a multirow element?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

In the tabular environment, horizontal alignment is traditionally achieved using such arguments as `l`, `c`, and `r` for the table spec. However, when `\multirow` (from package multirow) is used, the chosen alignment seems to no longer apply. This example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|p{5cm}|}
 \multirow{2}{2.3cm}{text1 text1 text1} & text2 \\
 & text3 \\
 & text4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: MWE showing left-aligned text in column 1]

The problem is that "text1" is left-aligned despite the fact that the first column was created using an 'r' argument to tabular. **How can I specify the alignment of the text in the multirow element?** For example, how could I right-align or center it instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you specify a width in `\multirow`, it is essentially a `p` column, so you specify alignment in the same way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|p{5cm}|}
 \multirow{2}{2.3cm}{\raggedleft text1 text1 text1} & text2 \\
 & text3 \\
 & text4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the same way"?

Comment: @Cerran I mean without `multirow` or any other package, if you want to align text in a `p` column or `\parbox` you use `\centering`, `\raggedright`, or `\raggedleft`. `multirow` works just like those standard latex constructs.